# grails, unit test mock domain with assigned id

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am using assigned id in my domain

```
class Book {

Integer id
String name

static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned'
    }   
}
```

so to add a new book:

```
def book = new Book([name: "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"])
book.id = 123
book.save(flush: true)
```

everything works perfectly, the problem is in my unit tests

first of all I can only mock 1 domain class,
secondly, I cannot use .save() on unit test, so my only option (as far as i know) is to use mockDomain as follow:

```
mockDomain(Book, [ [id: 123, name: "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"] ])
```

but it is not working, it would work in a normal domain without "id generator: 'assigned'"

any ideas?
I read that I wouldn't face this problem in integrated test, it is just a problem in unit test
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need the `bindable` constraint for `id` if you want to use (by default `id` is not `bindable`) it as map params to create the domain object in unit test. The domain class would have

```
static constraints = {
    id bindable: true
}
```

**Words of advice:**
If you are using Grails > 2.x, use `@Mock` to mock domain classes instead of `mockDomain`. You can find details about [Unit Testing](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTesting) in Grails docs.

**Another Level Up**
Use [`build-test-data`](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin to mock domain objects.

Comment: Thanks, will try the bindable:true,
for @Mock, as I mentioned I can only Mock 1 domain in a test file, so if I need to mock more than 1, i have to use mockDomain, unless there are other ways to mock more than one domain that i don't know

Answer (score 2):

This solution fits my needs:

```
Book mockBook = [name: "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"] as Book
mockBook.metaClass.id = 123
assert mockBook.id == 123
```